# How to declare a vector of vector in Julia

Tags: syntax, julia

I want to declare a vector of vector in Julia like the following

V = [v1, v2, v3,...] 
where v1, v2, v3... have dimension of K x 1

What is the syntax to achieve this?

Comment: An empty array? `V = Array{Vector,1}()` or do you want to initialise with values? FYI in julia vectors are just aliases for flat Arrays.

Comment: It depends a bit on the version of Julia. But in 0.5/0.6, `[v1,v2]` with `v1` and `v2` vectors simply works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Vector{Vector{Float64}}(5)`to declare a length-5 vector of floating point vectors, for example, or  `Vector{Vector{Float64}}(0)`for an empty one. But this doesn't really allocate memory, since the size of each contained vector is undefined.

If you want to actually allocate memory, you can use a comprehension like this:

```
V = [Vector{Float64}(5) for _ in 1:10]
```

for a length 10 vector of length 5 vectors. If you want to initialize to zero, do

```
V = [zeros(5) for _ in 1:10]
```

Comment: Note that this only works in Julia <= 0.7. See my answer below for modified version that works in Julia 1.0+.

Answer (score 9):

In Julia 1.0+ the accepted answer no longer works.

Now you must do something like:

```
V = [Vector{Float64}(undef,5) for _ in 1:10]
```